# reading from a file but first line being read is wrong

Tags: c, file-io

```
int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    int testNumber;
    char answerKey[5];

    fp = fopen("test.txt", "r");

    for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
    {
        fscanf(fp, "%s %d\n", answerKey, &testNumber);

        printf("%s %d\n", answerKey, testNumber);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am reading from a file that has this in it:

dbbac 10

dabac 8

dcbdc 1

dbbac 5

my output is this :

dbbac

10

daba 8

dcbdc 1

dbbac 5

Why is the first line read wrong? Why is there an extra next line?

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`answerKey` is not long enough. To hold 5 chars and a terminating string, it needs to be defined to be an array of at least 6 characters:

```
char answerKey[6];
```